# Can multiple virtual workers share a same collection? (BluePrism)

Tags: blueprism, rpa

I am working on a problem where i have to write data from a csv file into a collection. 
Ex: I have a csv file with 20 items. These items are added to the queue. Each time a case from the queue is processed, i am writing the item number into a collection. At the end, i am converting the collection to csv format. This works perfectly with 1 virtual worker. However, when i use multiple workers, they are only writing the item number that they are processing into the collection therefore the collection doesn't have the item number's of the cases worked by another virtual worker.

Is there a way for multiple workers to share a collection so that i don't have to loose any information before converting it to a csv file.? Basically i want all the items worked into a collection regardless of which worker worked on it.

Thanks in advance. Let me know if you require more information regarding this issue.

Comment: It sounds like you should re-factor your design to more heavily utilize the queue for each CSV item as a queue item. Then, re-use the work items in a separate process (designed to be run on a single machine) to write out the file you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

For all I know, there is no way for more multiple users to access the same collection during runtime. You can try different approaches however:

1. Do you have the item number in the starting CSV file as well? If so, then just add item number to queue data when adding items to the queue and make the last working resource (the one processing last pending item) loop through worked items in this batch (you can use tags to differentiate batches of work) and then pass data to the collection.

If you receive item number while processing it, then just add it to queue data once it's processed and then loop through the queue once whole batch is processed, just like described above.

Queue data is stored in the queue until you delete them manually while collection's data is being removed once the session is over, so you will be able to retrieve queue data anytime, which is an advantage in my opinion.

2. You can add single item's data into the CSV file directly after each item is worked. You would need to add some logic, so the resource acquires lock before trying to write data into file, to avoid possible exceptions when 2 or more resources try to access the file at the same time.

Hope this helps.